# How to use custom docker storage in Prefect flows?

Tags: docker, dask, prefect

I have setup a `Dask` cluster and i'm happily sending basic `Prefect` flows to it.
Now i want to do something more interesting and take a custom docker image with my python library on it and execute flows/tasks on the dask cluster.

My assumption was I could leave the dask cluster (scheduler and workers) as they are with their own python environment (after checking all the various message passing libraries have the matching versions everywhere). That is to say, i do not expect to need to add my library to those machines if the Flow is executed within my custom `storage`.
However either I have not set up storage correctly or it is not safe to assume the above. In other words, perhaps when pickling objects in my custom library, the Dask cluster *does* need to know about my python library. Suppose i have some generic python library called `data`...

```py
import prefect    
from prefect.engine.executors import DaskExecutor
#see https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/environments/storage.html#docker
from prefect.environments.storage import Docker

#option 1
storage = Docker(registry_url="gcr.io/my-project/",
                 python_dependencies=["some-extra-public-package"],
                 dockerfile="/path/to/Dockerfile")
#this is the docker build and register workflow!
#storage.build()

#or option 2, specify image directly
storage = Docker(
        registry_url="gcr.io/my-project/", image_name="my-image", image_tag="latest"
    )

#storage.build()

def get_tasks():
    return [
        "gs://path/to/task.yaml"
           ]

@prefect.task
def run_task(uri):
    #fails because this data needs to be pickled ??
    from data.tasks import TaskBase
    task =  TaskBase.from_task_uri(uri)
    #task.run()
    return "done"

with prefect.Flow("dask-example",
                 storage = storage) as flow:
    #chain stuff...
    result =  run_task.map(uri=get_tasks())

executor = DaskExecutor(address="tcp://127.0.01:8080")
flow.run(executor=executor)
```

Can anyone explain how/if this type of docker-based workflow should work?

Answer (score 4):

Your dask workers will need access to the same python libraries that your tasks rely on to run.  The simplest way to achieve this is to run your dask workers using the same image as your Flow.  You could do this manually, or using something like the [DaskCloudProviderEnvironment](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/environments/execution.html#daskcloudproviderenvironment) that will create short-lived Dask clusters per-flow run using the same image automatically.

Comment: Thanks Chris. this makes sense, i will follow that route. I just wanted to be sure that tasks could not be containerized in this way, particularly if i wanted to use a preexisting dask cluster as the execution environment. i cant upvote but your answer addresses my uncertainty.